# Ant Design: Move Position sub menu to the top of screen

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, antd

It is possible to move sub menu position to top of the screen. I am using the new menu component. Which way to declare it is to use it, all you have to do is write `<Menu mode= {mode} theme={theme} items={items}/>`.

Submenu position on default:
[image: default sub menu position]

And this is my expected condition:
[image]

The blue line is menu, and the red line is submenu. The way I did before was to create a new menu and place it at the top of the screen
But I think it will be a lot of trouble if you use it that way. So I want to switch ways by moving the sub menu to the top of the screen. Is that really possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always override the ant design css styles to achieve this. The sub menu items are the usual `ul` & `li` pair. To display `li` items in a line we just need to -

```
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

We can apply the same to ant design menu items & a few tweaks -

```
.ant-menu-vertical.ant-menu-sub > .ant-menu-item {
  display: inline;
}

.ant-menu-submenu-popup {
  top: 0px !important;
  right: 5% !important;
  left: auto !important;
  width: 400px;
}
```

[image: Edit Vertical menu - antd@4.21.0 (forked)]

Output

[image: antd design menu]

Comment: Whoaa it's really amazing sir, apparently we can do that,  thank you very much sir