# Ant Design How to customize header of Tab in ANTD's Tab in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I want to customize the header of the tabs component ANTD. For example, I want to add some div on that component. Based on the documentation we can use [this way](https://ant.design/components/tabs/#components-tabs-demo-custom-tab-bar).

Which way is to use the react sticky library. But that library is no longer supported for react 18. It gives an error:
[image]

What I really want to do is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569066/ant-design-move-position-sub-menu-to-the-top-of-screen). But if I use that method it will be difficult to make it look responsive.

Is there any other way or alternative to customize the header of the tabs component?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried affecting your styling with the use of the 'tabBarStyle' property

Adding a div inside the tabpane or outside covering all tabs should work